# Google font is not displaying in SVG code

Tags: svg, fonts, font-face, google-fonts

On [this page](http://2vsk.liepaja.edu.lv/Tenses/index_new_svg_embed.php) , I have an SVG code. The SVG file only shows the basic REGULAR type of font. Though, I have used all font variations (italic, bold, bolditalic, semibold, dark).

I have tried both, @import method and link rel, both within the file and external CSS. Those would be respectively.

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn:400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i');

I have also looked into this [solution](http://%3Cstyle%3E%20@import%20url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn:400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i');%20%3C/style%3E), where it is set within the SVG file with @font-face method (tried bold, regular, etc., to no avail):

Code snippet:

```html
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 5390.3 959.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 5390.3 959.3;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 @import {font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif; src: url('Vollkorn/Vollkorn-Bold.ttf')}
    svg{font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;}
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, even though your are setting

```
svg{font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;}
```

the classes for your text are over-witing the font family, with rules like the following.

```
.st22{font-family:'Vollkorn-SemiBold';}
```

"Volkorn-SemiBold" isn't defined anywhere.  Change your classes so that they just use "Volkorn"

```
.st22{font-family:'Vollkorn';}
```

or remove them altogether, since they now don't do anything.

Comment: If you use the @import clause with the googleapi stylesheet, the various font variants _are_ imported, but you have to target them by setting `font-family:Vollkorn;font-weight:600` etc.

Comment: This works. Thank you. I wish Google automated this for SVGs by "catching" the fonts by their respective names. Illustrator just outputs the name of the font when you export SVG code or save an SVG file.

Comment: A side issue, if I may. The SVG code is not rendering correctly in some places where text styles changes to underline. Thus I get + sign overlap onto a word.

I guess I have to modify the matrix coordinates to fix that or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Illustrator seems to be directly positioning the various bits of text every time the style changes.  I'm not sure if there is a way you can stop Illustrator doing that. You don't need to start a new position `<text>` element just to make a word underlined.  See [before](http://jsfiddle.net/yrh109c4/6/) and [after](http://jsfiddle.net/yrh109c4/14/). Note however that the length of the text will obviously be different.  But you can use the `textLength` attribute to fix that (see "after" example).